# Unable to view applications in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a paid-for Office 365 Developer account that I have accessed the underlying Azure subscription for.

Using the Azure Portal I created an "Application" in the Azure Active Directory for the account.  I was able to save it and the Azure Portal reported "Success".

However trying to view the application(s) by clicking the "Applications" link in the WAAD in the Azure portal gives me this error.

[image]

"Could not load the list of applications.  Try again later".

The "Details" button says

"Please try again.  If the problem persists, contact support".

I have tried again.  It doesn't work.

I have also tried to contact *Microsoft Azure support*, but they keep rejecting the issue because it is not "Billing Related".

Has anyone else had this issue and overcome it?  Or has anyone actually had any luck logging a call with Azure Support?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Free support is only for billing issues, that's why you are being rejected. The proper support is paid (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) What about if wait couple of minutes and refresh the entire portal - does the problem still exist?

Comment: I've waited days and it still exists.   I don't see this as a "Technical Problem" that I should pay to resolve ( I already pay for the Azure service ) but rather I view it as a "Functional Bug" within Azure that Microsoft should resolve.  All I am asking for it to do is to list the applications within the Azure AD.  That is core functionality and not a special technical requirement.

Comment: I don't see another option but dealing with the paid technical support. What does the "Details (i)" button on the right side of the pane says about the error?

Comment: The Details Button said "Try later.  Contact support if the problem persists".  **Ok, now the good news** I used the Azure Active Directory Powershell commands to list all the "Applications" ( Get-MsolServicePrincipal ) that were within the AAD.   I was then able to use the "Remove" command to start taking away the entries one-by-one.  Eventually I must have deleted the one entry causing the problem ... because now it is fixed and working.

Comment: Interesting issue. You should add what you did as an answer (and accept it).

Comment: Did you only have applications that you had created youself?

Comment: Yep, add your resolution as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually resolved this problem.

I used the Azure Active Directory Powershell commands to list all the "Applications" ( Get-MsolServicePrincipal ) that were within the AAD.

I was then able to use the "Remove" command to start taking away the entries one-by-one. Eventually I must have deleted the one entry causing the problem ... because now it is fixed and